# Awk print certain lines in a certain format

Tags: awk, formatting, printf

I have a text file containing the following information.

```
Table X1: Circuit Thermal Overload Ratings for xxx
Rated Temperature: 50 ºC 
ALL RATINGS ARE Winter Spring / Autumn Summer 
PER CIRCUIT Amps MVA Amps MVA Amps MVA 
Pre-Fault Continuous 485 111 450 103 390 89 
Post-Fault Continuous 580 132 540 123 465 106   

Table X2: Circuit Thermal Overload Ratings for xxx 
Rated Temperature: 65 ºC 
ALL RATINGS ARE Winter Spring / Autumn Summer 
PER CIRCUIT Amps MVA Amps MVA Amps MVA 
Pre-Fault Continuous 555 126 520 119 470 108 
Post-Fault Continuous 660 150 620 142 560 128
```

An image of the example table is here:
[example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mquvI.png)

I wish to format the lines depending on the first field of each line. 
For lines starting with 'Pre' or 'Post', insert commas after the first string and between every two numbers. 
printf("%s %s,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8)
For lines starting with 'ALL', insert commas after 'ARE', 'Winter' and 'Autumn'.
For lines starting with 'PER', insert commas after 'CIRCUIT', 'Amps' and 'MVA'.
For other lines, keep the original text...

The expected output should look like,

- ALL RATINGS ARE, Winter, Spring / Autumn, Summer
- PER CIRCUIT, Amps, MVA, Amps, MVA, Amps, MVA
- Pre-Fault Continuous, 555, 126, 520, 119, 470, 108
- Post-Fault Continuous, 660, 150, 620, 142, 560, 128

I have tried the following but it does not produce the results I am looking for. Any help would be greatly appreciated...

```
/Table/
{for(n=0; n<=5; n=n+1) {
    if(n<2){getline}
    if(n==2)
        {printf("%s%s%s,%s,%s%s%s,%s",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8)}
    if(n==3)
        {printf("%s%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8)}
    if(n==4||n==5)
        {printf("%s %s,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding the sample table into the question but it does not come out right. You could view the table by clicking on the image link...

Comment: better now, do add the expected output too

Comment: I did the data formatting for you, but it's work investing time learning the basics if you want to use this site.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I am new here...

Comment: Use of `getline` is rarely warranted and is NOT for beginners. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline. [edit] your question to include the expected output given your posted sample input (use the editor's `{}` button for formatting) so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is not going to help, instead use pattern matching.  Here is a template you can follow

```
$ awk '/^ALL/ {print ...; next}
       /^PER/ {print ...; next}
       /^Pre/ || /^Post/ {print ...; next}
       {print}'  file
```